# Position relative behaves differently than it used to

Tags: css

Why and when did Chromium change the behavior position `relative`?

Here is an example of the current behaviour. I would expect the offset of `#box1` to also shift `#box2` downwards, as it used to do so? Instead, it's now as if `#box1` is positioned absolutely (<strike>in relation to its current position</strike>) in the sense that `#box2` and the rest of the document completely ignore the offset of `#box1`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

#box1 {
  top: 20px;
  background: green;
}

#box2 {
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div id='box1'></div>
<div id='box2'></div>
```

This has made it so incredibly difficult to achieve something that should be so simple. What I am trying to do is place a button dead smack in the center of the page. When the user clicks the button, additional boxes are added to the list, positioned relatively.

[image]

The list container's height probably should be the same height as the page, so that everything should move upwards towards the top of the page when I scroll through the list.

[image]

This use to be easy to do by giving the button a `relative` position, and then placing it halfway down the page. I remember position `relative` you used to reflow other elements, but not anymore? Now I am completely dumbfounded.

I guess I could use a pseudo element to offset the first child now that I think of it.

Anyways, two questions:

1. When and why did Chromium change the behavior position `relative`? (Or am I tripping and it was never changed?)
2. How can I go about achieving something like this when the dimensions of the document are unknown since the page is responsive?

Comment: position:relative is something very very old so I don't think there is any change. Either you are facing a bug or you are missunderstanding position:relative. In both cases when need to see your code to help

Comment: *Instead, it's now as if #box1 is positioned absolutely (in relation to its current position) in the sense that #box2 and the rest of the document completely ignore the offset of #box1.* --> it was always like that ... *The offset does not affect the position of any other elements; thus, the space given for the element in the page layout is the same as if position were static.*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @TemaniAfif hmm ok im not sure why i remember it being different

Comment: @TemaniAfif hey u mind checking out this [question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927207/center-responsive-elements-in-horizontal-scroll-container)