# Center responsive elements in horizontal scroll container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a container (red border with line denoting the center) that scrolls horizontally if there is overflow.

The first child (purple block) of this container is always a button.

[image]

When you click this button, it adds additional children to the container.

[image]

What I am trying to do is figure out a way with pure CSS, so that the first child is always centered when the app is loaded, and the last child element in the container, if there is more than one child, can also be scrolled to the very center of the container.

I am having difficulties figuring this out because I have applied a `min-width` (i.e. `100px`) in addition to a responsive `width` (i.e. `25vw`) to the child elements.

The way I was initially planning on achieving this was by applying a `padding-left` to the parent container, and then an `::after` pseudo element to `:not(.first-child).children:last-child`, but then I realized the approach is not sufficient if I want it to be completely responsive. However, I know I can manually calculate at which width `min-width` will be triggered and then use a `@media` query, but I am hoping there is a better way.

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: ; /* Half the window width minus half the width of the child. */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: skyblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.children {
  width: 25vw;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: purple;
}

:not(.first-child).children:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  width: ; /* Half the window width minus half the width of the child. */
  height: 100%;
  position: relative; /* relative or absolute      */
  left: ;             /* and offset appropriately. */
  transform: ;        /*                           */
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: why not use `padding-left: 25vw;`?

Comment: @MatanSanbira because the `width` is `25vw`, but more importantly there is a `min-width` on the child elements

Comment: so maybe throw away the `min-width` and use @media for small screens

Comment: @MatanSanbira i could, but im not sure i have to. plus, i dont want to, especially if i dont have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a strictly responsive solution using `calc`, even though I am using `vh` as the `width` of the children. CSS is a savior.

```
#container {
--offset: calc(50vw - ((100vh / 100) * 20);
  padding-left: var(--offset);
  background: skyblue;
}

.children {
  min-width: 40vh; /* vh is used for width to account for the height of window. */
  min-height: 60vh;
  position: relative;
  background: purple;
}

:not(.first-child).children:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  width: var(--offset);
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `margin-left` to the first child and to deal with the min-width you can use media query. When the screen is less than `400px` the `25vw` will be less than `100px` and you change the value to consider the `100px`.

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/1px 100% no-repeat,
    skyblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.children {
  width: 25vw;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 40%;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: purple;
  flex-shrink:0; /* don't forget this to avoid the shrink */
}

.children:first-child {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 12.5vw);
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
  .children:first-child {
    width: 25vw;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Without media query you can consider a pseudo element where you will have a `max-width` constraint:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/1px 100% no-repeat,
    skyblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.children {
  width: 25vw;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 40%;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: purple;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

#container:before { 
  content:"";
  width: calc(50% - 12.5vw);
  max-width:calc(50% - 50px);
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ill test out the pseudo element approach when i wake up tomorrow

Comment: has the SO website been messed up lately?

Comment: yeah like when i load pages, sometimes elements are or text is all over the place and i have to refresh the page to get everything working properly

Comment: i just realized that the `width` of the children needs to be responsive, but it also needs to account for the height of the browser window, so currently im using `width: 40vh` (and `height: 60vh`). is there a way to do it this way? perhaps using the fluid [typography formula](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/)??

Comment: @oldboy my code still apply, you simply need to use `calc(50% - X)` where X is half the width you define for your element

Comment: did you overlook the fact that im using the height unit `vh` as its `width`?

Comment: i figured out a way to do it: `padding-left: calc(50vw - ((100vh / 100) * 20));` since the width of the child is now `40vh` i.e. half the width of the window `50vw` minus half the width of the child `100vh / 100 * 20`

Comment: figured it out. i posted it below

Comment: @oldboy `vh` doesn't make any difference. Apply it to the width then inside my formula use half of it (20vh) instead of 12.5vw and it will work

Comment: good to know, but i think i like my solution better. thanks for taking the time to share ur knowledge tho!!

Comment: any idea how to do this for a vertical scrolling container without explicitly setting the `height` for its children, but rather while the height of the children is determined by `font-size` and `padding`?

Comment: hey buddy, i [posted a question for it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976406/vertical-scrolling-first-and-last-child-centered-on-screen)