# Vertical scrolling, first and last child centered on screen

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a height of `100vh`. The children do not have an explicit height (i.e. `10vh`, `200px`, etc), but rather their `height` is determined by `font-size` and `padding`. I would like to be able to scroll the container ***vertically,*** whereby the first child and last child can always be scrolled to the very center of the screen.

[Here is how I accomplished it scrolling horizontally instead of vertically.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59927207/7543162)

**Is it even possible to do without setting an explicit `height` for the children?**

My attempt to solve this was to unfortunately add additional children elements (actual elements and not pseudo elements) with `&nbsp` as their content (to generate the same height as the other children) to the beginning and the end of the list, and then apply `transformY(-50%)` and `transformY(50%)` to them respectively, but this obviously does not work. The problem is that the transforms obviously don't effect the other children in the list.

Comment: *height is determined by font-size and padding* --> all of them will have different height?

Comment: @TemaniAfif all the children will have the same height (i.e. same `font-size` and `padding` and thus they will all implicitly share the same `line-height`). ill update my question with my current "solution" that doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to make your last element with height equal to 0 and rely on your translate trick. You will need at least one wrapper where you apply the `height:0` and another inside that will overflow:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px no-repeat,
    skyblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 2px;
  padding-top:50vh;
  padding-bottom:calc(50vh - 5px);
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.children {
  width: 25vw;
  min-width: 100px;
  font-size:25px;
  color:#fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink:0;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
.children > * {
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) center/100% 1px no-repeat,
    purple;
  padding:5px;
}
.children:last-child {
  height:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="children"><div>some <br>content here</div></div>
  <div class="children"><div>some <br>content here</div></div>
  <div class="children"><div>some <br>content here</div></div>
  <div class="children"><div>some <br>content here</div></div>
  <div class="children"><div>some <br>content here</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i was just about say that perhaps something like `display: grid` with `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, and then sizing the rows as the height of the content may work. about your example, it doesnt look like the last and first items are exactly centered (maybe because the borders)? ill play around with your idea

Comment: @oldboy I added another gradient to show they are exactly centred

Comment: @oldboy the border may probably create a small offset in the gradient but it's only about 1px at the worst

Comment: last one is centered, first child is not. i think its the borders. anyways, why does this work? is it specifically because `translateY(-50%)` and `last-child { height: 0}`?

Comment: @oldboy the translate will move all of them by half the height so logically at the bottom you will have a half height missing until the center. If the last child is height:0 it will not affect the overall height and its content will overflow to fill the missing half and another half after the center to be centred

Comment: ahhh right right right. i didnt get a good sleep last night, so my thinking isnt at its best right now. what is the purpose of nesting `divs` within the children?? is there one?

Comment: @oldboy since the main div has a height:0 you will need the nested one to apply all the styling if needed (border, background, padding, etc). Only needed for the last element by the way but it's easy to make it for all and have a generic CSS